# Pandas combine mutilple columns in a BQ table to generate payload for FB conversions api

Tags: pandas, dataframe, facebook-graph-api, google-bigquery

I am reading from a bigquery table to generate a payload to upload to FB conversions api.

cols=["payload","client_user_agent","event_source_url"]
I am copying the column values directly from the bq table as I am unable to print the full output of the dataframe in note book.

```
payload="{"pageDetail":{"pageName":"Confirmation","pageContentType":"cart","pageSiteSection":"cart","breadcrumbs":[{"title":"Home","url":"/en/home.html"},{"title":"Cart","url":"/cart"},{"title":"Confirmation","url":"/order-confirmation="}],"pageCategory":"Home","pageCategory1":"Cart","pageCategory2":"Confirmation","proBtbGlobalHeader":false},"orderDetails":{"hceid":"3b94a","orderConfirmed":true,"orderDate":"2021-01-15","orderId":"0123","unique":2,"pricingSummary":{"total":54.01},"items":[{"productId":"0456","quantity":1,"shippingAddress":{"postalCode":"V4N 3X3"},"promotion":{"voucherCode":null},"clickToInstall":{"eligible":false}},{"productId":"0789","quantity":1,"fulfillment":{"fulfillmentCost":""},"shippingAddress":{"postalCode":"A4N 3Y3"},"promotion":{"voucherCode":null},"clickToInstall":{"eligible":false}}],"billingAddress":{"postalCode":"M$X1A7"}},"event":{"type":"Load","page":"Confirmation","timestamp":1610706772998,"language":"English","url":"https://www"}}"

client_user_agent="Mozilla/5.0"
event_source_url= "https://www.def.com="
```

I need the value for email=[orderDetails][hceid] and value=["orderDetails"]["pricingSummary"]["total"]

Initially all the payload I wanted was in a single column and I was able to achieve the uploads with the following code

```
import time
from facebook_business.adobjects.serverside.event import Event
from facebook_business.adobjects.serverside.event_request import EventRequest
from facebook_business.adobjects.serverside.user_data import UserData
from facebook_business.adobjects.serverside.custom_data import CustomData
from facebook_business.api import FacebookAdsApi
import pandas as pd
import json

FacebookAdsApi.init(access_token=access_token)
query='''SELECT  JSON_EXTRACT(payload, '$') AS payload FROM `project.dataset.events` WHERE eventType = 'Page Load' AND pagename = "Confirmation" limit 1'''
df = pd.read_gbq(query, project_id= project, dialect='standard')
payload = df.to_dict(orient="records")
for i in payload:
    #print(type(i["payload"]))
    k = json.loads(i["payload"])
    email = k["orderDetails"]["hcemuid"]
    user_data = UserData(email)
    value=k["orderDetails"]["pricingSummary"]["total"]
    order_id = k["orderDetails"]["orderId"]
    custom_data = CustomData(
        currency='CAD',
        value=value)
    event = Event(
        event_name='Purchase',
        event_time=int(time.time()),
        user_data=user_data,
        custom_data=custom_data,
        event_id = order_id,
        data_processing_options= [])
    events = [event]
    #print(events)
    event_request = EventRequest(
        events=events,
        test_event_code='TEST8609',
        pixel_id=pixel_id)
    #print(event_request)
    a=event_request.execute()
    print(a)
```

Now there are additional values client_user_agent that needs to be part of user data and event_source_url as parts of events in the above code that  are present as two different columns in GBQ table.

I have tried similar code as above for multiple columns but I am receiving a

```
TypeError: Object of type Series is not JSON serializable
```

So I tried concatenating the columns and then create a json serializable object but I am not able to do an upload.

Below is where I am stuck and lost and not sure how to proceed further any inputs appreciated.

```
import time
from facebook_business.adobjects.serverside.event import Event
from facebook_business.adobjects.serverside.event_request import EventRequest
from facebook_business.adobjects.serverside.user_data import UserData
from facebook_business.adobjects.serverside.custom_data import CustomData
from facebook_business.api import FacebookAdsApi
import pandas as pd
import json
FacebookAdsApi.init(access_token=access_token)
query='''SELECT  payload  AS payload,location.userAgent as client_user_agent,location.referrer as event_source_url FROM `project.Dataset.events` WHERE eventType = 'Page Load' AND pagename = "Confirmation" limit 1'''
df = pd.read_gbq(query, project_id= project, dialect='standard')
df.reset_index(drop=True, inplace=True)
payload = df.to_dict(orient="records")
print(payload)
## cols = ['payload', 'client_user_agent', 'event_source_url']
## df['combined'] = df[cols].apply(lambda row: ','.join(row.values.astype(str)), axis=1)
## del df["payload"]
## del df["client"]
## del df["source"]
## payload = df.to_dict(orient="records")
#tried concatinating all columns in a the dataframe but not able to create a valid json object for upload
columns = ['payload', 'client_user_agent', 'event_source_url']
df['payload'] = df['payload'].str.replace(r'}"$', '')
payload = df[columns].to_dict(orient='records')
print(payload)
## df = df.drop(columns=columns)
## pd.options.display.max_rows = 4000
# #print(payload)
# for i in payload:
#     print(i["payload"])
#     k = json.loads(i["payload"])
#     email = k["orderDetails"]["hcemuid"]
#     print(email)
```

I am following the instructions from this page:https://developers.facebook.com/docs/marketing-api/conversions-api

Answer (score 1):

I have used the bigquery json_extract_scalar function to extract data from nested column instead of pandas which is a relatively better solution for my scenario.